# save tags in windows without manually setting at least one

Tags: windows, metadata, exiftool

I have this code to save the tags in `'tags' in "Details" tab in property of file` of `windows`):

```
import exiftool

def add_tag_to_file(file_path, new_tag):
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
        # Get existing tags
        metadata = et.execute_json("-j", file_path)
        if metadata:
            existing_tags = metadata[0].get("QuickTime:Category", '')
            if isinstance(existing_tags, str):
                existing_tags=existing_tags.split(";")
        else:
            existing_tags = []

        # Print existing tags
        print(f"Existing tags for {file_path}: {', '.join(existing_tags)}")
        saveTheTags=False
        if '' in existing_tags:
            existing_tags.remove('')
            saveTheTags=True
        if new_tag not in existing_tags:
            existing_tags.append(new_tag)
            saveTheTags=True
        else:
            print(f"Tag '{new_tag}' already exists in {file_path}.")
        if saveTheTags:
            formatted_tags = ";".join(existing_tags)
    
            # Save the new tags to the file
            et.execute(f"-QuickTime:Category={formatted_tags}", "-overwrite_original", file_path)
            print(f"Tag '{new_tag}' added to {file_path}.")
```

this code sets the tags to `metadata[0]["QuickTime:Category"]` of file. but doesnt show tags in `'tags' in "Details" tab in property of file` when the at least one tag isnot manually set.

for i.e. if some tag like 'faf' is manually entered from windows ui, after adding tags with this code, they would be shown in `'tags' in "Details" tab in property of file`. but otherwise the tags wont been shown even they have been set with this code to `metadata[0]["QuickTime:Category"]`

if you tried this code please tell me are you experiencing the same thing or not?

any other code with for setting `'tags' in "Details" tab in property of file of windows` and doesnt have this problem, image and video files, are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the wrong tag.  For Windows to fill the "Tags" property for videos, you want to set the `Microsoft:Category` tag, not the `Quicktime:Category` tag.

See [this exiftool forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6591.msg32875#msg32875) to see what tags Windows will read/write and the corresponding Property Details.

Comment: thanks handled some part of the answer, but I dont know how to handle `Unicode` file paths or add tag to images. which parts do u thing I should add to another separate question?

Comment: can u tell me how can I modify these tag for .mkv files?

Comment: Exiftool doesn't edit MKV files, so you'll have to look for another program.  `ffmpeg` and `mkvtoolnix` are often used.  Even though is seems that `mp3tag` only edits mp3 files, it can also edit mkv files.

Comment: As for unicode in file paths, the Perl windows libraries that exiftool uses have long standing problems with non-ascii characters.  [Exiftool FAQ #18](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q18) gives some options, but they don't work for everyone.  Myself, the only solution that would work was [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window/57134096#57134096) but that can cause some GUI spacing problems in older programs.

Comment: I don't know of any Python library for dealing with MKV, though I would assume there might be a `ffmpeg` wrapper of some sort.

Comment: Ive solved the unicode problem but my I have problem with ffmpeg.
I know I can set `comments` with `ffmpeg -i jd.mkv -metadata comment="New Tags;sde;" jd2.mkv -y` but I want to set the `tags` in metadata and not `comments`. how to edit tags of mkv files with any package like ffmpeg which supports non-ascii files

Comment: To be honest, I don't there there is anything you can set in an MKV file that will show up under the Property>Details window.  If I recall, there isn't a defined set of metadata.  It's all in KEY:VALUE pairs.  Everything that does show up are details about the steams, such as bit rate, fps, etc.